# Remote Desktop Connection Logging Off

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, hanging

On a Window Server 2008 R2 machine I am having a problem with a particular remote desktop connection.  I experienced a slow log-off last night (windows in the RDP session was showing "logging off") so I closed the RDP client.  This morning when I tried to remote into this server it took me directly to the "logging off" screen, so overnight the server never successfully logged off of that session.

Another user has remoted into the server via RDP and tried to disconnect, reset and manually log-off my session from Remote Desktop Manager but still upon login, I'm taken back to the "logging off" page.

Any suggestions on how to free up this session or resolve this issue without a reboot would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! Nate

Comment: In the Remote Desktop Manager, is your session still shown in the list of connections after you try to login again (when you're met with the "Logging Out" screen)?  In other words, after you're disconnected from the Remote Desktop Manager, and you try to log in again, does your connection reappear in the list of sessions?

Comment: Tim, the session is always shown in the Remote Desktop Services Manager, even when I'm not actively connected with that user. Thanks, Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We applied this hot fix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979530 to the server and restarted and haven't seen the problem since.  We don't think it was necessarily caused by the issue this hot fix resolves since we only have 1 to 2 users RDPing into this server at a time.  Perhaps this may help some of you out there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disconnect the session with the help of the "Terminal Services Manager".
I don't know how the tool is called in Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7.

In Windows 2003 / Windows XP you could connect to the server via the Terminal Service Manager and disconnect the session.

Or try to restart the Windows service "Remote desktop services" on the Windows Server 2008 R2. The connected users should automatically be disconnected (never tried this before).

Greetings
grub

Comment: Grub, thank you for the information. We tried disconnecting the sessions through Remote Desktop Services Manager AKA. Terminal Services Manager.  We also tried to restart the Remote Desktop Services.  Unfortunately neither of these steps reset these connections.  Upon a login we still receive the "logging off" screen.

Comment: hmmm. as i understood you, you're still able to login with another user.

logon, open an administrative cmd and query the open sessions:
query session

look for the session id of your user and reset it:
reset session <id> /v

maybe this helps.